# Approximation algorithms for maximum-weight independent set when vertex's weight could be negative

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

There are many approximation algorithms for maximum-weight independent set. But most of them assume non-negative weights. Are there any algorithms that work for possible negative weights?

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the negative-weight vertices. Consider *any* independent set that includes a negative-weight vertex. If you remove that vertex, the resulting set is still an independent set, but you've increased its total weight.